# Why is there a character in json change in Bash or zsh terminal when running a python script?

Tags: python, json, bash, zsh

I have a simple python script. I'm trying to have persistent storage of a small dictionary. My script reads in a json file and creates a dictionary from it. Then I add a new pair to the dictionary. Then I write over the json file with the dictionary.

```
import json

def translate(word, my_dictionary):
  return my_dictionary[word]

def add_words_to(my_dictionary): 
  x = input("Let\'s add to the dictionary. Give me a word. ")
  y = input("Give me a definition. ")
  my_dictionary[x] = y
  write_file("data.json", my_dictionary)

def write_file(file, data):
  with open(file, "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(str(data))

def read_file(file):
  with open(file, "r") as json_file:
    dictionary = json.loads(json_file.read())
  return dictionary

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cosas = read_file("data.json")
    print_dictionary(cosas)
    add_words_to(cosas)
    newWord = str(input("Give me a word to translate. "))
    print(translate(newWord, cosas))
```

`{"bee": "abeja", "pumpkin": "calabaza", "owl": "búho", "seeds": "semillas", "new": "nueva"}`

Zsh Output:
`{u'owl': u'b\xfaho', u'bee': u'abeja', u'seeds': u'semillas', 'test': 'thisword', u'new': u'nueva', u'pumpkin': u'calabaza'}`

Bash Output:
`{'bee': 'abeja', 'pumpkin': 'calabaza', 'owl': 'búho', 'seeds': 'semillas', 'new': 'nueva', 'test': 'thisword'}`

I can fix the Python script so that it changes the single-quote to double-quotes. For zsh I think it's changing from ascii characters to unicode characters? That is not my question. My question is **why does this happen?** what's going on in the system terminal that causes it?

Also why do I need double-quotes when inputting a variable in ZSH but not Bash?

I am using ohmyzsh if that also changes things...

Comment: I think bash is loading python 2 and zsh 3

Comment: You appear to be running the script with two different versions of Python - only 2.x uses the `u'...'` notation, Unicode is the default in 3.x.

Comment: `json_file.write(str(data))` doesn't write JSON. Use `json.dump(json_file, data)`

Comment: FYI, `json.loads(json_file.read())` can be simplified to `json.load(json_file)`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone!

I had forgotten I added python3 alias to py in bash but not in zsh.

And the point of the script was, I was trying to learn how to use the JSON library, and @Barmar was correct I needed `json.dump(json_file, data)` not `json_file.write(data)`